# how to manipulate json data into ts file and again push values in a new array in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to separate JSON data and convert ENTDT into GMT time and after that, again I want to make it JSON data.

```
this._myservice.myservice(this.taskdesc).subscribe(data => {

var newdata = data.map(function(obj){

  var a = {};

  a.TASKDESC = obj.TASKDESC;
  a.ENTUSR = obj.ENTUSR;
  a.ENTDT = new Date(obj.ENTDT).toISOString()

  return a;

});


this.displayList = newdata;


})
```

> error--> property TASKDESC does not exist on type '{}'..

Comment: can you please provide your logs?

Comment: copied json response from postman , pastebin link - pastebin.com/14rAZG1x  ,   error is stated above, what else are you asking ?